# Is the maximum oxidation state of an element equal to it's valency?

Tags: atoms

I know maximum oxidation state has a sign and valeny doesn't.... But, if we remove the sign then, would it be equal to the valency of an element? I earlier assumed that valency was equal to the oxidation state (without the + or - sign) but later found cases where this wasn't the case.... so I've come up with something new that the maximum oxidation state is equal to it's valency (without the + or -). I'm just making sure if this is right, please do correct me if this is wrong! Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0):

Valence refers to the absolute number of electrons *lost or gained*. Oxidation state refers to *number* of electrons gained (-) or lost (+). For example, if an element had oxidation states of -2, -1 and +1, the *maximum* oxidation state is **+1**.

Since [*valence* is ambiguous, oxidation number is preferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_(chemistry)#Valence_versus_oxidation_state) now.

BTW, we can blame Ben Franklin, who arbitrarily assigned electrons a *negative* charge, for the oddity that *gaining* an electron *reduces* the oxidation state -- it wan't until more advanced technology enabled Thomson and Rutherford to show that electrons were the more mobile particles.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the ambiguity of the term valence, nowadays other notations are used in practice. Beside the system of oxidation numbers as used in Stock nomenclature for coordination compounds, and the lambda notation, as used in the IUPAC nomenclature of inorganic chemistry, oxidation state is a more clear indication of the electronic state of atoms in a molecule.

The oxidation state of an atom in a molecule gives the number of valence electrons it has gained or lost. In contrast to the valency number, the oxidation state can be positive (for an electropositive atom) or negative (for an electronegative atom).

Elements in a high oxidation state can have a valence higher than four. For example, in perchlorates, chlorine has seven valence bonds and ruthenium, in the +8 oxidation state in ruthenium tetroxide, has eight valence bonds.